# RouteUrl replace "&" with "&amp;" in query string parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, routes, querystringparameter

I have the following code:

```cs
@Url.RouteUrl("NewMessage", new { parentThreadId = Model.thread.id, cacheBustParam = currentUserId })
```

When the page get rendered the page source looks like:

```html
/somepath/newMessage/12345?cacheBustParam=123&amp;param1=value1&amp;param2=value2
```

As you can see instead of plain ampesands `&` it places `&amp;` in the query string params and that makes them unusable.
How can i instruct the @Url.RouteUrl not to encode the querystring?

Comment: please check there is space in parameter values

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using

```
@Html.Raw(Url.RouteUrl("NewMessage", new { parentThreadId = Model.thread.id, cacheBustParam = currentUserId }))
```

Comment: @Bharat The Html.Raw method decodes html entities.

In this case, Url.RouteUrl spits out "&amp;", and Html.Raw decodes "&amp;" into "&"